# InternalsVisibleTo attribute not compiling under XBuild (Mono 2.10.6) but works fine under VS2008

Tags: c#, mono, assemblies

I'm trying to compile an assembly named Pivot.Data which contains the following code:

> [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Pivot.Core,PublicKey=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")]

Then in Pivot.Core I'm doing (that is a static property declared "internal static bool ReplayInProgress"):

```
Pivot.Data.DataEngine.ReplayInProgress = false;
```

This works fine under VS2008 but does not on Mono 2.10.6 (using XBuild).  I've tried every combination of changing InternalVisiblesTo around so that it will work but with no luck.  Is there some .NET / Mono incompatibility here that I just don't know about?

**EDIT:** The specific errors are:

```
Engine.cs(142,43): error CS0122: `Pivot.Data.DataEngine.ReplayInProgress' is inaccessible due to its protection level
Engine.cs(142,43): error CS0122: `Pivot.Data.DataEngine.ReplayInProgress.set' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Comment: Attached the specific errors.

Comment: So the code *containing* `InternalsVisibleTo` compiled okay? Have you tried it between two not-strongly-named assemblies?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I just tried without strongly-naming the assemblies and the error doesn't occur if they're not.

Comment: Hmm. If I get a bit of time on a machine with a Mono installation, I'll give it a try...

Comment: Same thing happens to me with mono